# Removing pixels of a GeoTIFF based on a scalebar

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, color, radar

I wonder if it is possible to remove the pixels from a GeoTIFF based on a threshold of an scale bar using GDAL. For example I would like to remove the data below approx 12dBZ on the picture attached, also I attach the colorbar scale.
[image]

My raster is from NOAA radars (https://mrms.ncep.noaa.gov/data/RIDGEII/L2/KBRO/BREF_RAW/)

gdalinfo:

```
   (gdal_env) ➜  gdalinfo -stats KBRO_L2_BREF_RAW_20211006_062839.tif
    Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
    Files: KBRO_L2_BREF_RAW_20211006_062839.tif
    Size is 4000, 4000
    Coordinate System is:
    GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        CS[ellipsoidal,2],
            AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                ORDER[1],
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                ORDER[2],
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        USAGE[
            SCOPE["unknown"],
            AREA["World"],
            BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]]
    Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
    Origin = (-102.418999999999997,30.916000000000000)
    Pixel Size = (0.002500000000000,-0.002500000000000)
    Metadata:
      AREA_OR_POINT=Area
    Image Structure Metadata:
      COMPRESSION=LZW
      INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  (-102.4190000,  30.9160000) (102d25' 8.40"W, 30d54'57.60"N)
    Lower Left  (-102.4190000,  20.9160000) (102d25' 8.40"W, 20d54'57.60"N)
    Upper Right ( -92.4190000,  30.9160000) ( 92d25' 8.40"W, 30d54'57.60"N)
    Lower Right ( -92.4190000,  20.9160000) ( 92d25' 8.40"W, 20d54'57.60"N)
    Center      ( -97.4190000,  25.9160000) ( 97d25' 8.40"W, 25d54'57.60"N)
    Band 1 Block=4000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
      Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=12.217, StdDev=30.031
      Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
      Metadata:
        STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
        STATISTICS_MEAN=12.2173336875
        STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
        STATISTICS_STDDEV=30.031330604567
        STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
    Band 2 Block=4000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
      Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=20.674, StdDev=51.516
      Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
      Metadata:
        STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
        STATISTICS_MEAN=20.674134125
        STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
        STATISTICS_STDDEV=51.516353683141
        STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
    Band 3 Block=4000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
      Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=25.118, StdDev=60.995
      Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
      Metadata:
        STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
        STATISTICS_MEAN=25.117503
        STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
        STATISTICS_STDDEV=60.995158930197
        STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
    Band 4 Block=4000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
      Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=37.888, StdDev=90.697
      Metadata:
        STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
        STATISTICS_MEAN=37.8882346875
        STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
        STATISTICS_STDDEV=90.697196856228
        STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

Comment: No, not possible. Your raster doesn't contain the actual data values, it only contains the red, green, blue and alpha transparency (RGBA) rendering.  The colour ramp uses a complex multipart stretch, if it was a simpler classification, you could work out what RGB value equals a data value/range with a bit of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @user2856 that you're unable to directly filter the pixels based on the values in your scale bar, however, if you are ok with a (hacky) workaround, here is a potential solution using R package 'raster' and an unsupervised classification routine to create a mask layer. You'll likely want to play around with the parameters of the kmeans() function to get the results you want.

```
library(raster)

#read in image
image <- stack('KBRO_L2_BREF_RAW_20211006_080757.tif')

#get pixel values
nr <- getValues(image)

#set the seed generator
set.seed(99)

# Create 4 clusters, allow 200 iterations, start with 2 random sets using "Hartigan-Wong" method
kmncluster <- kmeans(na.omit(nr), centers = 4, iter.max = 200, nstart = 2, algorithm="Hartigan-Wong")

#make new raster with cluster values with same dimensions as band 1
knr <- setValues(image$KBRO_L2_BREF_RAW_20211006_080757.1, kmncluster2$cluster)

#specify to keep class to be preserved in mask
knr[knr!=2]<-NA

#mask image pixels with mask layer
output<- mask(image, knr2, filename="", inverse=TRUE, maskvalue=NA, updatevalue=NA, updateNA=FALSE)

#replace 0 with NA
output[output == 0] <- NA

#write output
writeRaster(output, 'masked_radar.tif', overwrite=TRUE)
```

Original Image:

[image]

Classified Raster (Note: class # 2 is the area we want to mask from the original):

[image]

Mask Layer:

[image]

Output Image:

[image]